# Computer won't boot from hard drive

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot, ssd

So, I have an old Toshiba Satellite laptop (intel processor, 8gb ram, dedicated and on-board graphics, 1tb/4gb HDD/SSD combo drive) that I was trying to install Linux on. It had windows 10 on it and it's been slow for a while now. First I burnt a basic Debian CD and installed it (I've now also tried a ubuntu CD. Scripted reboot after installation is fine and it loads into Gnome. It has an ethernet connection so acquiring packages is not a problem. The issue is that on any subsequent reboot, I am greeted with either a
`reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media
(indicative of checking disk slot)`
or
`Checking media presence......
Media Present......
Start PXE over IPv4, Press [ESC] to exit.`
(indicative of checking for boot-by-LAN)

Now, my boot order is HDD, ODD, USB, LAN. (I've also tried telling the computer to specifically boot from the HDD, but it just skips to something else) I have no USB plugged in, so it is clearly not recognizing that there is an OS on the HDD and moving on to the next step. The installer for Debian, Ubuntu, and the BIOS have never failed to see that there is a hard drive there, but after a reboot that wasn't scripted by an installer, the computer doesn't seem to be able to start the OS.

I've also tried swapping out the stock (old) hard drive that came with the pc with a new SSD I ordered online. Same results; installers/BIOS can see the drive, and can boot directly after installation but will not boot from HDD. This PC was working (albeit very slowly) just fine 2 days ago with windows 10.

ALSO (probably also important), when I was moving files off of my computer, I noticed that in some cases, when the computer was showing/calculating folder/file sizes, it was calculating completely wrong numbers. One folder was listed as over 3TB, wheras the hard drive for the entire computer was only 1TB.
In addition, the computer has quickly flashed error messages during installation of either OS, which I could only briefly see and were something like
ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed
E_LIMIT (20180531/psparse-516)

My real question is if it's a hardware issue that would make it beyond help, or if it's a software thing that I'm just doing wrong.

Comment: It sounds like the bootloader isn't being installed. Try creating the Debian image again. Can you post where you are downloading it from so we can double check you have the right one? Remember to put `@Eric F` in front of any comments if you are responding at all

Comment: Also, please clarify what OSes are now on your system and where each one is.

Comment: @EricF Debian image was downloaded from the debian site, [the amd64](https://www.debian.org/distrib/netinst) image; and the Ubuntu image was downloaded from the Ubuntu site [here](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).  Should I try getting a new image?

Comment: @fixer1234 Each time I installed debian or ubuntu again, I told it to use the whole drive, i.e. wipe the old OS.  Currently I have debian on the SSD and Ubuntu on the HDD/SSD combo. The combo drive is plugged into the only Hard Disk slot in the laptop, and the other is currently in an external enclosure (I didn't just plug the enclosure in when I swapped them, I physically took the combo drive out and put the SSD in; I just don't have a better place to store it right now).

Comment: Each time you installed Linux of some variety, did you have the installer wizard handle disk partitions and related setup for you automatically or did you select to do it manually and then specify how to partition, where to put GRUB, etc.?  Can you confirm that each GRUB was installed, and  on the same drive as the OS installation (i.e., it could have found an existing GRUB on the other drive and asked you if you want to just update that one, in which case one drive may not even contain GRUB)?  (cont'd)

Comment: Was the other drive connected at the time so GRUB could find it and include whatever OS was on that one?  Did the first (or either) GRUB ever work properly (get discovered, show you a menu, and boot), or has no GRUB ever worked?  Have you tried picking the boot device immediately on power-on (and will either work if you pick it that way)?

Comment: @fixer1234 Only one drive was connected at a time.  The laptop only has one slot for a hard drive.  I had each installation do its default settings and I had the OS take up the entire hard drive for its partition.  I don't remember having an option to choose where/what bootloader was installed (nor specific references to GRUB).  I never got a choice of OSs and I never had more than one OS on a drive at a time.  I can try installing debian and then Ubuntu to see if I get a GRUB choice.

Comment: Ok, that somewhat narrows things down.  If you only had one drive installed each time you installed Linux, it should have automatically installed GRUB on that drive and there would be no other drive to detect.  Afterwards, if that drive is the default boot device (i.e., you don't have a bootable optical disk or USB in when you power up), it should boot from that drive.  When you power on, the sequence should be: a brief hardware self test and beep, then a few second display of a few keys you can press for some hardware options like picking a boot device or going into machine settings. (cont'd)

Comment: If you don't make one of those selections within a few seconds, you should see a menu of a couple of boot choices (that's GRUB).   The first option will be that distro, and there's typically a few others like advanced or recovery options, maybe a memory test you can choose to run.  You get 5 or 10 seconds to make a choice and then it defaults to the first option (the distro), and boots up.  On the order of a minute later you should be at either a login screen or ready to work.  Knowing how far you get in that sequence narrows things down.  (cont'd)

Comment: The question also mentions the ACPI error message, which is a common problem.  Google "acpi error" and you'll find a lot of advice on how to deal with that.  It also wouldn't hurt to just rule out the drives getting corrupted or starting to fail.  Depending on what you have to boot with, check the SMART values for the drive to ensure it isn't failing, and run `chkdsk /R` or the equivalent, like `fsck` in linux.  Instructions for all of those things are readily available online.  Do the chkdsk or equivalent when you can let it run to completion, which can take hours.  (cont'd)

Comment: Those steps should either identify or fix the problems, or provide good diagnostics to identify the next step.

Comment: @fixer1234 Thanks for all the input.  I will look into the things you mentioned and update if it still isn't working.

Comment: @fixer1234 So, grub doesn't seem to reliably start.  Sometimes it does, and sometimes it doesn't.  I tried running the debian installer rescue mode and forcing a grub install to /dev/sda, but that gave me a fatal error.  It lists the device as having /dev/sda1, /dev/sda2, and dev/sda3; however, there is apparently only a shell in sda2 to use.

Comment: @fixer1234 I tried using it and running fsck on sda1 and sda3.  It found a dirty bit in sda1 and didn't seem to find anything in 3.  I had it fix the dirty bit.  It still won't install grub on any of the partitions. e2fsck says that /dev/sda3 contains a swap file system.  (bad magic number in superblock; superblock invalid)

Comment: @fixer1234  At this point, I'm considering getting a cheap new drive and testing it out on my main computer to make sure it works, then plugging it into the laptop to see what is really the issue here.  I suppose it's possible that my old HDD is dead and I got a dud SSD.  Either that or I trashed something on my system when I had the debian installer erase the entire drive in the first place, but I can't imagine what would brick a computer from just messing with the hard drive.

Comment: This sounds like one of those problems that will be very difficult to solve remotely.  There are too many factors.  And GRUB not starting reliably shouldn't happen; it should either work or not.  Your best bet will be to get some local support.  Do you have a friend who's a computer guru who can look at it?

Comment: @fixer1234 Alright, well thanks for taking the time.  I'll probably head to a local computer repair shop to take a look at it.  I don't think I know anyone local who has any expertise in this particular area.